# stsfld vs stfld

Tags: .net, il

Looking at the difference between the stfld and stsfld il op codes, the stfld has a null reference check while stsfld does not. Why is this? Is it because static fields are on the high-frequency heap and so they are not garbage collected?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stfld.aspx

> The stack transitional behavior, in sequential order, is:
>
> 1. An object reference or pointer is pushed onto the stack.
> 2. A value is pushed onto the stack.
> 3. The value and the object reference/pointer are popped from the
>      stack; the value of field in the object is replaced with the supplied
>      value.
>
> The stfld instruction replaces the value of a field of an object (type
>   O) or via a pointer (type native int, &, or *) with a given value.
>   Field is a metadata token that refers to a field member reference. The
>   stfld instruction can have a prefix of either or both of Unaligned and
>   Volatile.
>
> NullReferenceException is thrown if the object reference or pointer is
>   a null reference and the field isn't static.
>
> MissingFieldException is thrown if field is not found in the metadata.
>   This is typically checked when the Microsoft Intermediate Language
>   (MSIL) instruction is converted to native code, not at runtime.

Comment: the context of the null check is not clear - but one on the instance itself (this) would be normal while it would be unneeded to check for a static field.

Comment: @poupou not sure what is unclear but i've added text from the MSDN page for stfld op code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static members **never** have a target instance. If there are parameters (on a method), arg0 refers to the first parameter, not the target instance (aka `this`). Since there is no target-instance, a null check is meaningless: there is nothing to dereference.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, it's checking if the instance is null since it's an instance field. It isn't checking if the value is null.

Comment: @Dustin correct; it doesn't care about the *value* - that can be anything

Comment: Thanks, that's where I was going wrong. I was thinking "value" not "instance"